# Wanted: 'Super selector' or How focus the first visible "input" field that has no value?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I was wondering if it is possible to focus the **first empty visible "input" field** with only one jQuery **selector**: something like `$('superamazingselector').focus();`

With "input" fields I mean: *text areas*, *inputs* (not type="hidden"), *selects*, *radio buttons*, *unchecked checkbox fields*. I guess this 'super selector' would be very handy on many pages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
$(':input[value=""]:visible:not(:button):first, :checkbox:not(:checked):first').first().focus();
```

- [`:input`](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector) - pseudo-class selector for all form input elements (includes `<textarea>` and `<select>`)
- [`[value=""]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector) - `value` attribute is empty
- [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector) - filters out hidden elements (doesn't select `<input type="hidden" />`)
- [`:not(:button)`](http://api.jquery.com/button-selector) - [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector) a `<button>` or `<input type="button" />`
- [`:checkbox`](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector) - selects checkboxes
- [`:not(:checked)`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector) - checkboxes that are `:not()` checked

How you select radio buttons depends on your HTML structure for `<input type="radio" />`, I can't think of a one-size-fits-all selector that detects an unselected radio button group.

Comment: And how would that find a textarea?

Comment: @Kees - Yes, `:input` matches those too: http://api.jquery.com/input-selector @BoltClock - I think it should be `$(':input[value=""]:visible:first').focus();`

Comment: Very good... only one problem: if I put a <button>test</button> on top... it gets to focus.

Comment: @Kees - `$(":input[value='']:not(button):visible:first").focus()`

Comment: Very good... now when I have a '<input name="test" type="checkbox" />' it doesn't get the focus :-). It has something todo with the '[value=""]' part. When I remove that part I get the focus correctly... but that's not what we want.

Comment: @Kees: Because a checkbox's state is determined by `checked` not `value`.

Comment: I see... I've added it to the question as wel... can we perform somesort of or on value part, like: `[value="" || :unchecked]` ?

Comment: For performance I use this one: `$(':input[value=""]:not(:button):visible:first, :checkbox:not(:checked):first').first().focus();` so I added a two `:first` so it can stop looking for other controls.

Comment: @BoltClock, perfect. Can you add the two ':first'-s to your answer... then I'll mark it as 'answered'... thanks for the insight of ':input' :-) didn't know that one :P

Answer (score 3):

Nice question:

Give this a try:

```
$(':input[value=""]:visible:first').focus();
```

Comment: Edited code to better optimise for [input selectors](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

I think `$(":input:visible[value='']").first()` should do it.

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/U3r6C/1/

Comment: And how would that find a textarea?

Comment: And how will it discard a hidden input field?

Comment: @Kees it will discard hidden input with `:visible` and find textarea with `:input`